# sfml - image cannot display

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I create a sfml project with cmake on windows, but the image cannot display.

src/main.cpp

```cpp
#include "game.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    Game game;

    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time elapsed;
    float frametime = 1.0f / 60.0f;

    while (game.window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (game.window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                game.window.close();
            }
        }

        // 1. 事件处理
        game.handleInput();

        // 2. 更新物理逻辑
        if (elapsed.asSeconds() >= frametime) {
            elapsed -= sf::seconds(frametime);
            game.update(); // 60次/秒
        }
        elapsed += clock.restart();

        // 3. 渲染
        game.window.clear();
        game.render();
        game.window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

src/game.hpp

```cpp
class Game {
  public:
    sf::RenderWindow window;

    sf::Sprite s;

    Game() {
        window.create({320, 480}, "hello");

        sf::Texture t;
        t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.png");
        s.setTexture(t);
    }

    void handleInput() {}

    void update() {}

    void render() { window.draw(s); }
};
```

If I put draw code into `main.cpp` then it works. Like this:

src/main.cpp

```cpp
       ...
        // 3. 渲染
        game.window.clear();
        // game.render();
        sf::Texture t;
        t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.png");

        sf::Sprite s(t);
        game.window.draw(s);
        game.window.display();
       ...
```

I want to know how it work

Comment: @AhmedAEK oh my god, it work！I'm so excited，thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sfml has a FAQ for this [The White Square Problem](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem)

> This is a common mistake. When you set the texture of a sprite, all it
> does internally is store a pointer to the texture instance. Therefore,
> if the texture is destroyed or moves elsewhere in memory, the sprite
> ends up with an invalid texture pointer.
>
> You must correctly manage the lifetime of your textures and make sure that they live as long as they are used by any sprite.

you should store your `sf::Texture t` as a member of your class for it to have the same lifetime as your sprite, and your sprite won't be trying to draw a destroyed texture.